# Advantages and/or disadvantages with or without brackets

Tags: php, coding-style, tags

Apologies if this has already been covered but what are the advantages/disadvantages of using brackets?  Here's a couple of examples:

`exit;` or `exit();`

`include "configuration.php";` or `include("configuration.php");`

Is this just 'coding style', like the use of long and short tags or is there an actual difference?  If there isn't, why both typing in those extra two characters?

Comment: Those are not functions but language constructs.

Comment: Jack is right, this doesn't work for functions

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the documentation within the link `http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php` where it says `function.exit` - makes me think it's a function.

Comment: Anyway, that's not the question.  The question is, what's the difference?

Comment: There is no difference. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Those aren't brackets, those are parentheticals. `{}` would count as *curly braces*. On language constructs, unless I need them I omit.

Comment: @Titanium: Yeah, this is a great example of how the PHP manual is ridiculous. In some cases like this the URL says "function" then the page itself says "oh, hey, this actually isn't a function"; in this case it doesn't even bother with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are language constructs rather than functions, so that parentheses are not required. In fact, using parentheses there is about as useful as: `$five = (2+3);`

However, since they can take "parameters" (the exit code for `exit`, the filename for `include`) and some of them can even return values (`include` and related functions "return" whatever is returned by a `return` statement in the top level of the included file), it helps to treat them as though they were in fact functions.

Comment: `s/about as useful as/precisely as useful as/` in that they are doing the _precise_ same job.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know.